# Existence and construction of isomorphism between finite groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-isomorphism

Assume I have two finite groups $G$ and $H$ of equal order. Further assume I have found minimal generating sets $A$ and $B$ for a the two groups respectively (of equal size) and additionally (see comments) I know at least one decomposition into generating elements of all $g \in G$.

I now want to find out if the two groups are isomorphic give this extra information of the minimal generating sets.

Is there an approach along these lines:

Define a bijective function $f: A\to B$. Extend the function to all of $G$ in the following manner:
For $g \in G$ find a decomposition of $g = a_1 + \cdots + a_m$ where $a_i \in A$ and define $f(g) = \sum_{i=1}^m f(a_i)$. If this extension fulfills the homomorphism property $f(g_1 + g_2) = f(g_1) + f(g_2)$ for all $g_1, g_2 \in G$ then it is an isomorphism.

**Question 1**. Is the above statement correct? Do I need to check $f(G) = H$ or is this already implicitly true?

**Question 2**. Here I need to expand the function for all $g \in G$ and check the homomorphism property for all pairs of elements from $G$.
Given the information of two minimal generating sets, can I reduce the amount of checking I have to do?
(Checking only the pairs of generators is obviously not enough since the extension fulfills the homomorphism property for elements from $A$ by construction)

Comment: Are you assuming your groups are abelian?  How do you know that that the extension of $f$ that you define is independent of the choice of decomposition of $g$?  If, say, $a_1$ has order $3$ and $f(a_1)=b_1$ has order $2$ then $f(a_1^2)=b_1^2=e_H$ so your function isn't even a set theoretic bijection.

Comment: No I don't assume commutativity. Good point, I had not thought about that. Is there a way to rescue this?

Comment: Well, I don't know.  It's hard to say much about a group just knowing a generating set.

Comment: If the extension of $f$ were an isomorphism, then it must also be independent of the decomposition of any $g$. So perhaps it is not necessary to require (a-priori) that the extension of $f$ is bijective

Comment: You haven't even defined an extension of $f$, your definition depends on that independence.

Comment: Well I can define $f(g)$ for any $g$ given *some* decomposition of $g$. If this is not a well defined function (extension), then it is not an isomorphism.

Comment: Now you want to fix a decomposition of every element in $G$?  That wasn't part of your original data.  Just making $f$ into a homomorphism is going to be very difficult.  And, as I pointed out before, if your map on the generating set doesn't preserve order then there's really no way you'll get an isomorphism.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are hoping for,  I suggest you try to construct explicit, non-trivial examples of what you want to see.

Comment: Okay thanks for the input. I was trying to find an algorithm that can utilize the knowledge of minimal generating sets (and at least one decomposition of every group element) to check for isomorphism.

Comment: try this: if your minimal generating sets are of different sizes, the groups are not isomorphic. (e.g. a cyclic group and a non-cyclic group are not isomorphic).

Comment: if they ARE of the same size, rather than relying on a decomposition being in the image, leave it in the domain. define a map that takes generators to generators. now, using the decomposition in the doman, check whether this extends to an isomorphism. if it's not, change the map. If you are allowed to also change to another minimal generating set in the range, it _might_ be possible that you always find an isomorphism if it exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(I should state at the start that the ideas in the question are close to pretty standard ideas. All I am doing here is trying to explain the link to these standard ideas.)

There are two things you seem to be missing.

1. If $f$ is a homomorphism then its extension to the whole group is not necessarily a bijection. You need to verify that it is injective or surjective (or both if your group is infinite).
2. The image group $H$ may have *lots* of minimal generating sets. So you need to find *all* minimal generating sets $B_i$ (for speed you can take them up to conjugacy, or up to automorphism). For example, consider $\mathbb{Z}_3\times\mathbb{Z}_{18}$. This is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_6\times\mathbb{Z}_9$. One group is generated by an element of order $3$ and an element of order $18$, while the other is generated by an element of order $6$ and an element of order $9$.

The following is then true:

**Theorem.** Let $A$ be a minimal generating set for $G$, and let $\{B_i\}$ be the set of all minimal generating sets of $H$ which have cardinality $|A|$. Then $G\cong H$ if and only if there exists a bijection $f_{i, j}: A\rightarrow B_i$ which extends to an isomorphism $G\rightarrow H$ in the way you describe.

Note that you have to check that the extension is bijective *and* is a homomorphism. These are non-trivial tasks*. Also, the subscript $j$ is because there are *lots* of bijections between $A$ and $B_i$, but not all of these will extend to be a homomorphism.

*If $G$ is given by a presentation $\langle \mathbf{x}\mid\mathbf{r}\rangle$ (alternatively this presentation can be computed, but not necessarily quickly!, as your group is finite) then determining if $f$ is a homomorphism is relatively easy, as you just need to verify that $f(R)=_H1$ for all $R\in \mathbf{r}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So what you are implying that is not even sufficient to fix two generating sets $A$ and $B$ of G and H and check *all* extensions of *all* bijections $f: A \to B$ for bijectivity and homomorphism? Edit: So there might not even exists a bijective homomorphisms $G \to H$ that maps $A$ to $B$.

Comment: Nope! For example, consider $\mathbb{Z}_3\times\mathbb{Z}_{18}$. This is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_6\times\mathbb{Z}_9$. One group is generated by an element of order $3$ and an element of order $18$, while the other is generated by an element of order $6$ and an element of order $9$.

Comment: (I've added the above comment into the answer.)

Comment: Aiaiai, okay, I see. I assume restricting the generating sets to contain elements of the same order is not sufficient either, although coming up with a counter example might be a bit tricky?